# Regular expressions: include?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to search inside a "text.log" file to see if it contains "hello":

```
lines = File.readlines("text.log")
line = lines.join
```

I want it to return `true` in all the situations below(i want it to be case-insensitive):

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
line.include?("hello")
line.include?("HELlo")  
line.include?("HellO")
line.match(/"hello"/i)
line.include?(/"hello"/i)
```

Comment: Have a look at [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html)

Comment: What's your original string `"hello"` or `hello` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a recommendation, it helps a question gather answers if you use proper capitalization and grammar. If English is not your primary language it's understandable that the grammar might not be 100%, but please try to use correct capitalization because it helps us parse your question.

Comment: Why not let your OS do it? It will be a lot faster to use `grep` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double quotes.

```
line.match(/hello/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open('text.log') { |f| f.grep(/hello/i) }.any?
```